# sed command to print all line starting from and end to specific words present in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed

Suppose I have one file

File1 consist two Words

File1 : PAPER  TEAM

Now i need to print all the lines of a file M starting from word PAPER end to word Team

sed command to print between two words is  `sed -n "/PAPER/,/TEAM/p" file2`

But thing is right now I am directly giving words but it should check itself to words everytime in `file1` and grep the all lines starting from one word  to end to other  in other `file2`.

Answer (score 3):

```
while read -r first second ; do 
    sed -n "/${first//\//\\\/}/,/${second//\//\\\/}/p" file2 ; 
done < file1
```

note, that `${first//\//\\\/}` is used to replace possible `/` symbol to escape sequence `\/` cause otherwise contruction may be broken.

if you're completely sure you don't have `/` symbol in file1 then you can use just `$first` and `$second`.

Comment: `/` is not the only problem character. `.`, backslash (also for `read` unless you use `-r`), `^`, `[`, `$`, `*` also are.

Comment: This doesnt solve my problem actually File one having two words those i need to search in file2 in your code i am not getting how it is getting first and second from file 1

Comment: @yisha, these words are read with `read` in a `while` cycle.